# Database2Entities.SaveChanges() Not Working

Tags: c#

I have a .sdf databsae set up using entity framework. My code is below. However when I try to update the first record, it shows this correctly using console.writeline(), however when I "show table data" in visual studio, I can see the original value still there, it is not updated:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database2Entities context = new Database2Entities();

        DbSet<Product> products = context.Products;

        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(product.name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("---");

        Product prod = products.First();

        prod.name = "Faux lion fur hat";

        context.SaveChanges();

        products = context.Products;

        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(product.name);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
/*Output:
gloves
scarves
coates
lionFurHat
boots
---
Faux lion fur hat //This doesn't show in the diagram.
scarves
coates
lionFurHat
boots*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the real issue but maybe the old  context.Products; is being reassigned to the same products again try maybe using a different variable like

```
var productsUpdated=context.Products;
```

and you can also try to refresh it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503718.aspx

```
context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, Products);
```

Comment: that method doesn't exist for Database2Entities though.

Comment: you still have to clear the cashe obviously it a cashing issue

Comment: you can try to initiate the context again